# Theoretical supremacy of Gaussian SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Many packages such as sklearn use RBF kernel as default for SVM classification. I wonder if there is a proof/explanation why this is the "best" kernel for a general use.

Is there some analysis for the richness of boundaries that can be written as a_1*K(x,x_1)+...+a_m K(x,x_m)=0 for different kernels?

I am looking for some references.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK. I will post there. Thanks.

Comment: The boundaries calculated by an RBF kernel are just more flexible and can fit a lot more different data than e.g. a linear kernel. I don't think you can generalize this though, it is not always generally the "best" kernel, it always depends on the data you are trying to fit. I highly doubt you could prove that its the best for most data either.